# Can anyone tell me what is happening to my gas stove?

Tags: kitchens, gas-burner

I went to boil water with a stainless kettle "not a plastic container" but only 1 minute passed I smell something like melted plastic. So, I turn off the burner and found this thing on the burner which looks like melted plastic. I wonder what is happening because I didn't use any plastic containers at all. [image]

Comment: A plastic lid was stuck to the bottom of your kettle.  And you didn't notice it.

Comment: Show us a pic of the bottom of the kettle?

Comment: @SteveWellens  How often do you look at the bottom of a kettle.  If something that was smaller and thin was struck on the bottom, I think most of us would miss seeing it.  Hopefully we do not place a hot/warm kettle on something like that by mistake.

Comment: @crip659 my kettle gets placed on a stove or a trivet.

Comment: was it an electric kettle with a plastic base?

Answer (score 2):

A gas range is not capable of reaching the temperature needed to melt stainless steel and that debris on the burner does not appear to be stainless steel.  It appears to be some sort of plastic material.

It's pretty obvious that something that should not have been there was somehow stuck to the bottom of your kettle and that melted and dripped down on the burner.

You're going to need to carefully remove all of that material and make sure that it hasn't dripped down into the outlet holes and clogged them.  Also check your kettle and see if any of this is still adhering to the bottom.

Comment: Surprise that plastic looking stuff looks so clean.  Would have thought the gas burner would be hot enough to leave some burn marks on some of that, instead of just melting.